# First passage time of rolling dices

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose we have a fair 6-sided die, and keep rolling it until the product of the last two rolls is 6. I want to use Markov chain to find the expected number of rolls needed.

My idea is to use a state for each possible pair of rolls $(x, y)$. There are 36 possible combinations, so there are 36 states in total. (This ignores the first roll, because we can simply add 1 to our answer to compensate for that.) Each state has 6 edges coming in and 6 edges going out, and the transition probability is $\frac{1}{6}$ for all transitions.

There are 4 states whose products are 6: $(1, 6)$, $(6, 1)$, $(2, 3)$, and $(3, 2)$. Now I'm stuck how to proceed and compute the expected first passage time to any of the 4 states, starting at any possible state. I'm not sure if I'm on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to attack this type of problem is with an *absorbing* Markov chain. For each of the “goal” conditions, define an absorbing state—one that transitions only to itself with probability $1$. Since there’s no way for the product of successive rolls to be six if the previous roll was a 4 or 5, the process effectively starts over in that situation, so we end up with 6 states: the start state, which includes having rolled a 4 or 5, one state for each of the rolls that could lead to a product of 6, and the absorbing goal state. In canonical form, all of the absorbing states are placed last, so for this Markov chain we have the canonical-form matrix $$P = \begin{bmatrix} \frac13 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & 0 \\
\frac13 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & 0 & \frac16 \\
\frac13 & \frac16 & \frac16 & 0 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
\frac13 & \frac16 & 0 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\ 
\frac13 & 0 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The expected time until absorption given that you start in state $i$ is the sum of the expected number of visits to each of the transient states. From this you can set up a system of linear equations or, equivalently, use matrix operations on $P$. Let $Q$ be the upper-left $5\times5$ submatrix that covers only the transient states. Then $[Q^k]_{i,j}$ is the probability of being in state $j$ in exactly $k$ steps, starting from state $i$. Summing over all $k$, $$N=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Q^k = (I-Q)^{-1} $$ produces the *fundamental matrix* $N$, which gives the expected number of times that the system is in state $j$ given that it started in state $i$. The expected absorption times are then the row sums of $N$, i.e., $N\mathbf 1$, and the solution to this problem is the first element of this vector.

---

*Addition:* Since the transition probabilities have a nice symmetry, this system can be simplified by lumping states 2-5 together into a single “might stop on the next roll” state. The reduced transition matrix is $$P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac13 & \frac23 & 0 \\ \frac13 & \frac12 & \frac16 \\ 0 & 0& 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ This is small enough to solve by hand: $$I-Q = \begin{bmatrix} \frac23 & -\frac23 \\ -\frac13 & \frac12 \end{bmatrix} \\
N = (I-Q)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac92 & 6 \\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix} $$ and so the expected time to absorption is $\frac92 + 6 = \frac{21}2 = 10.5$.